# c#: Isn't Where(), OrderBy() and Select() from Enumerable Class supposed to take a delegate type, lambda expression or anonymous type as a parameter

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, anonymous, enumerable

I have got a question. See the two blocks of code. Isn't `Where()`, `OrderBy()` and `Select()` from `IEnumerable` Class supposed to take a delegate type, lambda expression or anonymous type as a parameter. If so, how did the `QueryOverStringWithRawDelegate()` produce the same results as `QueryOverStringsWithExtensionMethods()`?

```
void QueryOverStringsWithExtensionMethods()
{
    // Assume we have an array of strings
    string[] currentVideoGames = { "Morrowind", "Uncharted 2", "Fallout 3", "Daxter", "Bio Shock 4" };

    IEnumerable<string> subset = currentVideoGames.Where(game => game.Contains(" ")).OrderBy(game => game).Select(delegate (string game) { return game; });

    Console.WriteLine("Query Over Strings With Extension Method");
    foreach (var s in subset)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Items: {0}", s);
    }
}
```

and

```
void QueryStringsWithRawDelegates()
{
    // Assume we have an array of strings
    string[] currentVideoGames = { "Morrowind", "Uncharted 2", "Fallout 3", "Daxter", "Bio Shock 4" };


    var subset = currentVideoGames.Where(Filter).OrderBy(ProcessItems).Select(ProcessItems);

    foreach (var s in subset)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Items: {0}", s);
    }

    string ProcessItems(string game)
    {
        return game;
    }
    bool Filter(string game)
    {
        return game.Contains(" ");
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: If I were you I'd include the result in your question, and explain what you expected to happen.

Comment: Output : Uncharted 2, Fallout 3, Bio Shock 4 for both Methods() For the second method, I would expect an exception. As Where() supposed to take a Func<> as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
currentVideoGames.Where(Filter)
```

is simply shorthand for:

```
currentVideoGames.Where(new Func<string, bool>(Filter))
```

That is, the compiler sees that you've got a method which takes a delegate type `Func<string, bool>`, it sees that you're giving it a method which has the signature `bool Filter(string)` (strictly, a *method group* of one or more overloads, one of which has a signature that's close enough), and it automatically inserts the code to instantiate a new delegate instance.

This same language feature lets you write things like:

```
SomeEvent += Handler;
```

rather than:

```
SomeEvent += new EventHandler(Handler);
```

[See this on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAOgDIEsB2BHA3AWACgoBmBAJjgGE4BvIuRhMqAFjgFkAKASjoaaCkMANoBdOAGMArgCdZAU0wAXAGrpgCgPYBxAIYBbBQGc4AXjpwARBy3ytAdyzArAGmsBVTJIAWe2coKwHDkbtYAYnoANlFa0spwJGFWACJ6AB6BsskAQuhacADKPlqSANZwrFZwAL4EhIKCAo1wAG7+cABm6FFZQeZScooq6pq6hibIAOo+Copc4T1ZPPWCNc0tTBsADrLo7YFwAEZaWlFwi71zXMJw6Twb9A2bUADsd8hUWip6WMZc1SsKw260INSAA=).

---

Similarly:

```
currentVideoGames.Where(game => game.Contains(" "))
```

is shorthand for:

```
currentVideoGames.Where(new Func<string, bool>(CompilerGeneratedFunction))
```

where `CompilerGeneratedFunction` will look something like:

```
bool CompilerGeneratedFunction(string x)
{
    return x.Contains(" ");
}
```

[See this on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAOgDIEsB2BHA3AWACgoBmBAJjgGE4BvIuRhMqAFjgFkAKASjoaaCkMANoBdOAGMArgCdZAU0wAXAGrpgCgPYBxAIYBbBQGc4AXjpwARBy3ytAdyzArAGmsBVTJIAWe2coKwHDkbtYAYnoANlFa0spwJGFWACJ6AB6BsskAQuhacADKPlqSANZwrFZwAL4EhIKCAo1wAG7+cABm6FFZQeZScooq6pq6hibIAOo+Copc6eYAfHDpyFRaKnpYxlzVVjw89YI1RDVAA=). It so happens that the compiler's put `CompilerGeneratedFunction` (which it called `<M>b__0_0`) in a new inner class, and it caches the `Func<string, bool>` that it instantiates for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you canton7 for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

No, as you have observed, this is not an error. The compiler will translate method groups with the appropriate signatures into the corresponding Func<> types.